How do I allow the user to download the attached files?
The code on the frontend:
<template>
    <div class="task-page-container">
      <!-- Левый блок с информацией о задаче -->
      <div class="task-info-container">
        <!-- Вывод информации о задаче -->
        <div class="task-details">
          <h2>{{ task.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{ task.description }}</p>
          <p>Дедлайн: {{ formatDate(task.deadline) }}</p>
          <p>Статус: {{ task.status }}</p>
        </div>
  
        <!-- Прикрепленные файлы -->
        <div class="attached-files">
          <h3>Прикрепленные файлы</h3>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="file in task.files" :key="file.id">
              <a :href="file.path" :download="file.filename">{{ file.filename }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Правый блок с формой для редактирования задачи -->
      <div class="task-edit-container">
        <!-- Форма для редактирования задачи -->
        <form @submit.prevent="submitSolution">
          <h2>Решение задачи</h2>
          <!-- Поле для ввода текста решения -->
          <textarea v-model="solutionText" placeholder="Введите текст решения"></textarea>
  
          <!-- Поле для прикрепления файлов -->
          <input type="file" multiple accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf" >
  
          <!-- Выбор статуса задачи -->
          <select v-model="task.status">
            <option value="выполняется">Выполняется</option>
            <option value="завершена">Завершена</option>
          </select>
  
          <!-- Кнопка для отправки решения -->
          <button type="submit">Отправить решение</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
   import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    name: "TaskPage",
    data() {
      return {
        task: {},
        solutionText: '',
        solutionFiles: []
      };
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getTask();
    },
    methods: {
      getTask() {
        axios
            .get('/api/task/taskInfo', {
                headers: {
                'authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.access_token}`,
                'taskid': localStorage.task_id
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                this.task = response.data
            });
      },

The code on the backend:
export const taskInfo = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // поиск задачи
        const task = await TaskModel.findById(req.headers.taskid)
        .select('name description deadline createdDate status isImportant tags worker files solution')
        .populate({
            path: 'worker',
            select: 'surname name otch'
        });

        if (!task) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Задача не найдена'
            });
        }

        // получение информации о файлах, прикрепленных к задаче
        const taskFiles = task.files.map(file => ({
            path: `uploads/${file}`,
            filename: file,
        }));

        // получение информации о файлах, прикрепленных к решению
        const solutionFiles = task.solution.files.map(file => ({
            filename: file,
        }));

        const taskInfo = {
            ...task.toObject(),
            files: taskFiles,
            solution: {
                text: task.solution.text,
                files: solutionFiles
            }
        };

        return res.json(taskInfo);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Не удалось получить информацию о задаче'
        });
    }
}

Why is there an error when downloading a file that the file was not found on the server? The file itself, when attached by the user, is saved to the root folder "uploads".
I tried different options. Do I need to register a separate request for downloading files?

By "not found" do you mean  that it hits if (!task) condition? You need to isolate the problem, either to the FE (localStorage.task_id) or to the backend (req.headers.taskid). Currently only you can debug what taskid is, this would likely explain why TaskModel.findById fails. It's not very conventional to supply params through a header when query params are available but this shouldn't affect the way it works here
